# How to iterate/while a mapping variables from environment to message assembly in IBM Integration Bus (toolkit)?

Tags: mapping, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I have a SOAP node, that retrieve information from a URL in a tree structure.

Then i have a compute node to define each environment variable to each namespace variable of the SOAP retrieve.

And finally, i have a mapping node, to move the content to my message assembly structure in XML.

The error its giving me it's this (IN THE COMPUTE NODE):

I have a structure like this:

ListDocs

```
Description
DocType
ListTypes
 Attribute
 Lenght
 Description
 Nature
 Required
```

ListDocs

```
Description
DocType
ListTypes
 Attribute
 Lenght
 Description
 Nature
 Required
```

ListDocs

```
Description
DocType
ListTypes
 Attribute
 Lenght
 Description
 Nature
 Required
```

The problem is that, when i do the definition of the variables, I do it like the code below, in the COMPUTE NODE:

```
WHILE I < InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns:obterTiposDocProcessosResponse.ns:return.ns75:processo.ns75:listaTiposDocumentos  
DO

  SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.description = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs.ns75:description;

  SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.tipoDocumento = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs.ns75:DocType;

  SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.listTypes.attribute = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs.ns75:listTypes.ns75:atribbute;

  SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.listTypes.lenght = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs.ns75:listTypes.ns75:lenght;

  SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.listTypes.description = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs.ns75:listTypes.ns75:description;

  SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.listTypes.nature = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs.ns75:listTypes.ns75:nature;

  SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.listTypes.required = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs.ns75:listTypes.ns75:required;    

  SET I = I+1;

END WHILE;
```

BUT, in my XML final structure, it only prints the values of my first listDocs, and i want to print all of my listDocs structures.

NOTE: WITH THE WHILE LIKE THIS, IT DOESN'T EVEN WORK. I HAVE TO REMOVE THE WHILE TO PRINT THE FIRST listDocs like i said Above.

Any help?

I NEED HELP TO LOOP THE STRUCTURES, WITH A WHILE OR SOMETHING.

Comment: @JohnathanLeffler thank you for removing tag [esql] again, I replaced it in a earlier edit with the [extended-sql] tag but did not notice the OP added it back.  Programmer Master, as the tag wiki states "Do not use this tag because it is ambiguous." please leave it off the question since the tag [extended-sql] is specific to the "ESQL" that IIB uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the following synthax :

```
DECLARE I INTEGER 1;
DECLARE J INTEGER;
J = CARDINALITY(InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns:obterTiposDocProcessosResponse.ns:return.ns75:processo.ns75:listaTiposDocumentos[])
WHILE I <= J DO
   SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.description = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[I].ns75:description;
   ....
END WHILE;
```

You only missed the CARDINALITY function to get the number of elements, and also the [] to define the table, and then using this [I] while accessing the elements

Note : in my sample above, the environment will be overridden at each iteration of the loop, so only the last record will be printed. You can use the [I] in the output as well if you want to construct a table in output, or you can use the following code to push each message to the output terminal (this means you have one message in input, and 3 message coming out of the output terminal)

```
PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'Out';
```

So for example, based on your code, if you want to generate 3 messages based on your input containing multiple element :

```
DECLARE I INTEGER 1;
DECLARE J INTEGER;
J = CARDINALITY(InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns:obterTiposDocProcessosResponse.ns:return.ns75:processo.ns75:listaTiposDocumentos[])
WHILE I <= J DO
   SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.description = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[I].ns75:description;
   SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.tipoDocumento = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[I].ns75:DocType;
   SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.listTypes.attribute = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[I].ns75:listTypes.ns75:atribbute;
   SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.listTypes.lenght = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[I].ns75:listTypes.ns75:lenght;
   SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.listTypes.description = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[I].ns75:listTypes.ns75:description;
   SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.listTypes.nature = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[I].ns75:listTypes.ns75:nature;
   SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs.listTypes.required = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[I].ns75:listTypes.ns75:required;
   PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'Out';
END WHILE;
RETURN FALSE;
```

For your global information, the RETURN TRUE is the instruction "pushing" the message built in the ESQL code to the output terminal. If you use PROPAGATE instruction (same effect), you should RETURN FALSE to avoid sending an empty message after looping on your records. Another way to do it is to propagate on another terminal (i.e : 'out1'), and keep the return true. In this case, you would have all you records coming out from the out1 terminal, and a message going out of the output temrinal (due to the return true) once all the messages have been propagated (this might be useful in many situations)

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply
Putting the code as you said, and the [I] in each output in front of listDocs, it don't print any record, not the first (as it prints without the while) and nothing else, it comes empty...

Comment: Ok, so... you were absolutely right, i just needed to make some adjustments.

Now i'm having the problem that it only prints the last one... where do i put the propagate? inside the while? can you past the code exactly? I didn't get that part sorry

Comment: Hello, yes, the propagate instruction will basically generate a new output, so it should be inside the while, just before (or after) the I = I + 1;, I just updated my answer with the code

Comment: This is not working with the propagate
Im doing the instruction as you said (after or before the SET) inside the while, but i'm putting my Body.getdocstructuretype as output but he keeps giving an error (only accepts INTEGER or CHARACTER)... but my output structure is not from that type...

Comment: Do you know other way to print all ? and not just the last result?

Or a fix to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, I did a small typo, the propagation shoud be 'Out' and not 'output', i'll fix my answer. Your issue might be due to the fact that propagating a message is by default "deleting" the current output message. I don't know your case, but maybe you have to use PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'Out' DELETE NONE

Answer (score 0):

So the key to understanding IIB and ESQL is that you are looking at in memory Trees built from nodes.

Each Node has pointers/REFERENCEs to PARENT, NEXTSIBLING, PREVSIBLING, FIRSTCHILD and LASTCHILD Nodes.

Nodes also have FIELDNAME, FIELDNAMESPACE, FIELDTYPE and FIELDVALUE attributes.

And last but not least that you are building Output Trees by navigating Input Trees. The Environment Tree, which you are using, is a special long lasting Tree that you can both read from and write to.

So in your code **InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs** can be thought of as shorthand for instructions to navigate to the **ns75:listDocs** Node. The dots '.' tell ESQL interpreter the name of the child Node of the current Node. If you were telling someone how to navigate the Nodes it would go something like this.

1. Start at **InputRoot**. InputRoot is a special Node that is automatically available to you in your ESQL Modules code.
2. Navigate to the first child Node of **InputRoot** that has the name **SOAP**
3. Navigate to the first child Node of **SOAP** that has the name **Body**
4. Navigate to the first child Node of **Body** that has the name **listDocs** and is in the **ns75** namespace.

In the absence of a subscript ESQL assumes you want the first Node that matches the specified name **ns75:listDocs** and **ns75:listDocs[1]** both refer to the same Node.

This explains what was happening in your code. You were always navigating to the same **listDocs[1]** node in the **InputRoot** and **Environment** Trees.

@Jerem's code improves on what you were doing by at least navigating across the **listDocs** nodes in the Input tree.

For each iteration of the loop the subscript [I] gets incremented and thus it chooses a different **listDocs** Node. The **listDocs** Nodes are siblings and thus the code will access the first, second and third instance of the **listDocs** Nodes.

```
InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[1] <-- Iteration I=1
InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[2] <-- Iteration I=2
InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[3] <-- Iteration I=3
```

To correct @Jerem's answer you'd need to use subscripts on the lefthand side of the statement as well. Picking the **description** field as an example you'd need to change your code as follows.

```
SET Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process.listDocs[I].listTypes.description = InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs[I].ns75:listTypes.ns75:description;
```

Using subscripts is regarded as a performance no no. Imagine you had 10,000 **listDocs** this would result in each and every iteration of the loop walking down the tree over the **InputRoot**, **SOAP**, **Body**, **ns75:processo** Nodes and then across the **listDocs** sibling nodes until it found the **ns75:listDocs[I]** Node.

This means by the time we get round to processing **ns75:listDocs[10000]** it will have had to repetetively walked over all the other **listDocs** Nodes time and time again, In fact we can calculate it would have walked over (4 x 10,000) + ((10,000 x (10,000 + 1)) / 2) = 50,045,000 Nodes

So it's REFERENCE's to the rescue and **also the answer to your question**. Try a loop like this.

```
DECLARE ns75 NAMESPACE 'http://something.or.other.from.your.wsdl';
DECLARE InListDocsRef REFERENCE TO 
InputRoot.SOAP.Body.ns75:processo.ns75:listDocs;
WHILE LASTMOVE(InListDocsRef) DO
    DECLARE EnvListDocsRef REFERENCE TO Environment;
    CREATE LASTCHILD OF Environment.Variables.XMLMessage.return.process AS EnvListDocsRef NAME 'listDocs';

    SET EnvListDocsRef.description           = InListDocsRef.ns75:description;
    SET EnvListDocsRef.tipoDocumento         = InListDocsRef.ns75:DocType;
    SET EnvListDocsRef.listTypes.attribute   = InListDocsRef.ns75:listTypes.ns75:atribbute;
    SET EnvListDocsRef.listTypes.lenght      = InListDocsRef.ns75:listTypes.ns75:lenght;
    SET EnvListDocsRef.listTypes.description = InListDocsRef.ns75:listTypes.ns75:description;
    SET EnvListDocsRef.listTypes.nature      = InListDocsRef.ns75:listTypes.ns75:nature;
    SET EnvListDocsRef.listTypes.required    = InListDocsRef.ns75:listTypes.ns75:required;    

    MOVE InListDocsRef NEXTSIBLING REPEAT NAME;
END WHILE;
```

The code above only walks over 4 + 10,000 Nodes i.e. 10 thousand Nodes vs 50 million Nodes.

A couple of other useful things to know about setting references are:

1. To point to the last element you can use a subscript of **[<]**. So to point to the last **ListItem** in the aggregate **MyList** you would code  **Environment.MyList.ListItem[<]**
2. You can use an asterisk ***** to set a reference to an element in the tree that you don't know the name of e.g. **Environment.MyAggregate.*** points to the first child of MyAggregate regardless of it's name.
3. You can also use asterisks ***** to choose an element irregardless of it's namespace **InListDocsRef.*:listTypes.*:description**
4. For anonymous namespaced elements use ***:***  but be very careful ***** and ***:*** are not the same thing the first means no namespace any element and the second means any namespace any element.
5. To process lists in reverse combine the **[<]** subscript with the **PREVIOUSSIBLING** option of **MOVE**.

So a chunk of code for reversing a list might go something like:

```
DECLARE MyReverseListItemWalkingRef REFERENCE TO Environment.MyList.ListItem[<];
WHILE LASTMOVE(MyReverseListItemWalkingRef) DO
    CREATE LASTCHILD OF OuputRoot.ReversedList.Item NAME 'Description' VALUE MyReverseListItemWalkingRef.Desc;

    MOVE MyReverseListItemWalkingRef PREVIOUSSIBLING REPEAT NAME;
END WHILE;
```

Learn how to use REFERENCES they are extremely powerful and one of your simplest options when it comes to performance.

Comment: Have you tried the debugger or a user trace. If you can't get to these easily can you please paste the contents of the errors or exception list

Comment: Do you have a WSDL for this service